# LESS selector for element and child?

Tags: less

With LESS how can I apply styles to both a selector and the selector within it?

My demo I need to apply opacity and z-index to the class a, and to label that come directly after it.

```
.a {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 2;
  & + label {
    color: blue;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple `&, & + label` :)

Comment: Even more short: `&, + label` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the complete answer, to help others with same doubt. To achieve desired result, original code could become:

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
.a 
{
  &,
  & + label
  {
    color: red;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  & + label
  {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Firstly you define common properties for both selectors with `,` separator and then you'll override only `color` property for `& + label` one.

**SOLUTION 2:**

If you want, you could achieve the same result using first class `.a` as a mixin and then overriding again `color` property:

```
.a
{
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 2;
}

a + label
{
  .a;
  color: blue;
}
```